# Truncated Poisson vs Hurdle model: why different values?

Tags: r, statistics, empirical-distribution

I want to do a regression with count data model, where doctor visits is the dependent variable. I did a two-part model with first a probit model for no doctor visit at all or one or more and then a Poisson model for at least one doctor visit. After that, I did a hurdle model as a robustness check, because as far as I know, I should get very similar values for both approaches. I do get nearly the same values for the probit part. I get, however, very different values for the Poisson part. Does anyone have any idea why? Here are the commands I used:

```
probit_doc <- glm(docbin ~ phi + gender +  age + health + educ + smoke + logthinc + 
                    wave + AUS + GER + SWE + NED + ESP + ITA + FRA + DEN + GRE + 
                    SWI + BEL + ISR + CZE + POL + LUX + HUN + POR + SVN + EST + 
                    CRO + LIT + BUL + CYP + FIN + LVA + MAL + ROM, 
                  data=allwaves, family=binomial(link="probit"))
  
poisson_doc <- glm(I(doc > 0) ~ phi + gender + age + health + educ + smoke + 
                     logthinc + wave + AUS + GER + SWE + NED + ESP + ITA + FRA +
                     DEN + GRE + SWI + BEL + ISR + CZE + POL + LUX + HUN + POR +
                     SVN + EST + CRO + LIT + BUL + CYP + FIN + LVA + MAL + ROM,
                   data=allwaves, family="poisson")
  
hd_doc <- hurdle(doc ~ phi + gender + age + educ + smoke + logthinc + wave + 
                   AUS + GER + SWE + NED + ESP + ITA + FRA + DEN + GRE + SWI +
                   BEL + ISR + CZE + POL + LUX + HUN + POR + SVN + EST + CRO +
                   LIT + BUL + CYP + FIN + LVA + MAL + ROM | phi + gender +  
                   age + health + educ + smoke + logthinc + wave + AUS + GER + 
                   SWE + NED + ESP + ITA + FRA + DEN + GRE + SWI + BEL + ISR + 
                   CZE + POL + LUX + HUN + POR + SVN + EST + CRO + LIT + BUL + 
                   CYP + FIN + LVA + MAL + ROM,
                 dist="poisson", data=allwaves, zero.dist="binomial", link="probit")
```

Comment: Since you're doing `glm(I(doc > 0) ~ ., family='poisson')` in your "poisson" model, `doc` gets binarized and it's rather a binomial model, have you tried `glm(doc ~ ., family='poisson', data=subset(allwaves, doc > 0)`?

Answer (score 1):

In a hurdle model we usually calculate a *zero* part using a `binomial` model for the "hurdle", and a *count* part for what happens after the "hurdle" was passed. Accordingly, in the zero part we binarize the outcome on if it is unequal to zero, as you did correctly.

In the count part however, only the observations that have passed the hurdle are taken into account. So rather than manipulating the outcome variable as we did in the zero model, we want to `subset` the data to observations that have values unequal to zero.

Consider this example from the `pscl` package which you are obviously using.

```
library(pscl)
hurdle(art ~ ., dist="poisson", zero.dist="binomial", link="probit", data=bioChemists)$coe
# $count
# (Intercept)    femWomen  marMarried        kid5         phd        ment 
#  0.67113931 -0.22858266  0.09648499 -0.14218756 -0.01272637  0.01874548 
# 
# $zero
# (Intercept)    femWomen  marMarried        kid5         phd        ment 
#  0.15420081 -0.14616546  0.19834717 -0.17380191  0.01864404  0.04433777
```

We may replicate the zero part by binarizing the outcome variable `I(art > 0)`.

```
## zero model
glm(I(art > 0) ~ ., family=binomial(link='probit'), bioChemists)$coe
# (Intercept)    femWomen  marMarried        kid5         phd        ment 
#  0.15420081 -0.14616546  0.19834717 -0.17380191  0.01864405  0.04433781
```

For the count part, if we binarize the outcome variable `I(art > 0)` we get wrong results.

```
## count model misspecified
glm(I(art > 0) ~ ., family=poisson(), bioChemists)$coe  
# (Intercept)    femWomen  marMarried        kid5         phd        ment 
# -0.52364397 -0.07020092  0.08944930 -0.08814266  0.01987790  0.01258345
```

Instead, we want to `subset` the data on observations where the outcome is non-zero, and the values already better resemble those of the `hurdle`.

```
## count model correctly specified
glm(art ~ ., family=poisson(), subset(bioChemists, art > 0))$coe
# (Intercept)    femWomen  marMarried        kid5         phd        ment 
#  0.82722135 -0.16220935  0.06824070 -0.09902318 -0.01311912  0.01504273
```

However, as you actually stated in your title, `hurdle` is calculating a *truncated* poisson model, which is also known as *positive poisson distribution* whereas you used a conventional poisson in the `glm`.

The `VGAM` package provides a `pospoisson` family function which gives exactly what we want.

```
VGAM::vglm(art ~ ., family=VGAM::pospoisson(), subset(bioChemists, art > 0)) |> 
  coefficients()
# (Intercept)    femWomen  marMarried        kid5         phd        ment 
#  0.67113934 -0.22858262  0.09648498 -0.14218724 -0.01272657  0.01874550
```

The visual comparison of the two distributions shows that positive poisson is indeed better suited to fit the count part of a hurdle model.

[image]